# How to set a variable to the result of a select statement in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to set the value of a variable to the result of a simple select statement.

```
var datevar varchar(10);
exec :datevar := SELECT trunc(sysdate) from dual;
select :datevar ASOF from dual
```

I get the error message below. I'm working with Oracle 12c

[image]

How can I get this to work without using PL/SQL? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, it won't work in SQL layer, but will in PL/SQL. In SQL*Plus, there's `exec` you can use (as you already know). It kind of "replaces" `begin-end` and lets you type a few less letters than you usually should.

So, on your example: as it is PL/SQL, you'll need the `INTO` clause:

```
SQL> var datevar varchar2(10);
SQL> exec select trunc(sysdate) into :datevar from dual;   --> note INTO

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print datevar

DATEVAR
--------------------------------
21.07.2020

SQL>
```

---

What `exec` actually does is

```
SQL> begin                                               --> behind the scene, EXEC encloses 
  2    select trunc(sysdate) into :datevar from dual;    --> your statement into
  3  end;                                                --> BEGIN - END
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print datevar

DATEVAR
--------------------------------
21.07.2020

SQL>
```

---

Finally, to answer your question:

> How can I get this to work without using PL/SQL?

You can't.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you **CAN'T** apply to a variable in sqlplus the result of a query.

```
SQL> var datevar varchar(10);
SQL> exec :datevar := '20200721' ;
SQL> select :datevar from dual ;

:DATEVAR
--------------------------------
20200721
```

You can also apply them to filters in where conditions

```
SQL> variable v1 varchar2(20)
SQL> exec :v1 := '2015/12/22';
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select 1 as result from dual where to_date(:v1, 'yyyy/mm/dd') < sysdate;

    RESULT
----------
         1
```

But if you need to dynamically assign a value to a variable, you need PL/SQL. Which is the right way

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>  declare
 my_var varchar2(10);
 begin
 select trunc(sysdate) into my_var from dual;
 dbms_output.put_line ( my_var );
 end;
 /  

21-JUL-20

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: can you accept the answer please ? it would be appreciated